# Is it possible to reformat python __all__ statement with ruff to make it multiline?

Tags: python, ruff

I'm using `ruff` (https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/). Is it possible to format the code from this:

```
__all__ = ["Model", "User", "Account"]
```

Into this?

```
__all__ = [
    "Model",
    "User",
    "Account"
]
```

Comment: That's an opinionated format style, and not the most common one. Usually, the style you want, is used for bigger lists, if the list only contains a couple of objects then is better to type it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. `ruff` has amazing feature called `magic-trailing-comma`. If you want your list, no matter how long is it, to be one line just don't put comma after the last element:

```
def some_func(a, b, c):
    ...
```

```
__all__ = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

In case you want your function args or list elements to be one per line just put a magic trailing comma after the last element:

```
def some_func(
    a, 
    b, 
    c,
):
    ...
```

```
__all__ = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
]
```

Comment: Just for some context, this feature is borrowed from `black` that `ruff` reimplements almost 1:1, and works the same way there.